# listener event on a button

Tags: angular

I want to check if a button has been clicked

```
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let p of arrray; let i = index"  >
<button class="btn btn-success"  (click)="onLoveIt(i)" >Love it!</button> &nbsp;
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And you're doing that already. So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: You don't need to attribute an ID to your button. You are already passing the index of array item that is being clicked as parameter. If you need, pass the array item itself too.

Comment: After that check, what you want to do with it ? changing css or something ?

Comment: yes @bubbles change to css

Comment: @bubbles change background-color of the li

Comment: my problem is not on how to change the background-color my problem is on how to guess which button is clicked @bubbles

Comment: ok can you add the last explanation to your question ? i mean changing the css of the li element

Answer (score 0):

use onLoveIt(this) instead. So that you will have a reference to the element who sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

From your question your are passing the index of the li to the `onLoveIt(i)` method. So i understand that you are not using a property in the `p` object to determine which button is clicked (or which property is modified).

We can create another array which contains boolean values and change the css based on it, like:

```
// in your component and after the initilization of your `arrray`
this.liChecked = arrray.map(e => false);
```

```js
onLoveIt(i) {
...
this.liChecked[i] = true;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let p of arrray; let i = index"  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': liChecked[i] ? 'red' : 'green'}">
   <button class="btn btn-success"  (click)="onLoveIt(i)" >Love it!</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```